# mvn site fails due to dependency resolution

Tags: maven, maven-site-plugin

I want to run the site lifecycle after an mvn verify, but it fails.

to be precise:

```
mvn versions:set -DnextSnapshot=true
mvn install
mvn site
# works

mvn versions:set -DnextSnapshot=true
mvn verify
mvn site
# fails
```

The project is a bom-based multimodule project consisting of:

```
pom.xml                 - root bom
modules/pom.xml         - has pom.xml as parent
modules/ci-lib/pom.xml  - has modules/pom.xml as parent - library project
modules/ci-main/pom.xml - has modules/pom.xml as parent - uses the library project
```

for more details, see https://github.com/helt/ez-ci

Error details are quite obvious (`mvn -X`), but I wonder why the dependency resolution does not look into the project artifacts itself...

```
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata de.fhg.igd.iva.examples:ci-lib:1.0.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\foobar\.m2\repository)
```

Is there a way to tell maven-site-plugin to look up all information in the respective `target/` directories of this project? Any other idea how to fix it is also appreciated...

Comment: <inputDirectory> can be specified for this plugin. mvn install implicitly runs mvn verify anyway.

Comment: @rootkonda InputDirectory is used in site:deploy, not site:site and seems to be used for telling maven where the output of mvn site:site is located. This won't solve my dependency issue here, or?